# Hangfire .NET Core 3.1 background task schedule error

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

I have a background task in Hangfire configured daily at 16 o'clock, but Hangfire does not read the task at the correct time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg26T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5NCf.png)

In the image the cron expression is for daily at 16 o'clock and the hour of the server is 14:40 hours but Hangfire says that the next execution is in 17 hours but it should be in two hours or less

Comment: Please check your time zone--Hangfire works in UTC if I recall correctly. You will need to translate your time zone to UTC.